# How to truncate Django Measurement object to 2 decimal points

Tags: python, django

I computed a distance between a user location and nearby apartments as a queryset. I got a distance queryset annotation in Django. Its precision is overly exaggerated and unnecessary, I want to limit the precision to 2 or 3 decimal points. I have tried to format it with string formatting but didn't work. How can I truncate distance measurement objects in django to 2-3 decimal places?

Comment: Can you share your model?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the [**`round(…)`** builtin function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> round(Decimal('0.123456789'), 2)
Decimal('0.12')
>>> round(Decimal('0.123456789'), 3)
Decimal('0.123')
```

You can thus construct a new `Decimal` by rounding a `Decimal` with a given number of decimals.

Comment: I think Measurement objects are incompatible for arithmetic operation. I tried Decimal, but threw error.

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam: of course, you need to obtain the field/item and then run that *item* (so the annotation) through the `round` function, not the entire `Measurement` object.

Comment: I don't have a measurement field, it is computed between a user location and apartments nearby. Do I need to store it to database to compute the distance?

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam: I think it will help (a lot) if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67113879/edit) the question and share the relevant details to make your problem *reproducible*.

Answer (score 0):

For conversions, access the preferred unit attribute to get a converted distance quantity:

```
d1 = Distance(km=5)

print(d1.mi) # Converting 5 kilometers to miles
    3.10685596119
print(d2.km) # Converting 5 miles to kilometers
    8.04672
```

source [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/measure/)